# Bird song ID app for Android that is audio only

Tags: android, audio

I'm looking for an app to help one learn birds by their song for Android. I've tried several, and the ones I've tried all use images and text to identify the bird while they play the song.

A key piece of functionality is that this must be **audio only** -- I'm looking for a voice to say the name of the bird when its song is played.

I listen to various audio at work -- podcasts, music, white noise, etc. I want to learn bird songs, but I can't be looking at my screen all the time. I need this to be an audio-only app.

Comment: Have you tried to search for an podcast that goes through different birds e.g. this [Podcast](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/34jF1nwh8Z32sbB92dH23yf/listen-and-learn-a-beginner-s-guide-to-identifying-birdsong).

If you are looking for an app that recognizes Birds by sound you might have a look at [BirdNET](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tu_chemnitz.mi.kahst.birdnet) but it dosn't speak out the results...

Answer (score 0):

The [Warblr app](https://www.warblr.co.uk/) recognizes British/European birds by their song. It is available for Android and iPhone.